# Drawing a Vertical Pyramid

Tags: c#, console

I am having a little problem here, I want to draw a vertical pyramid like this:

```
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
OOOOO
OOOO
OOO
OO
O
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it. All I get is:

```
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
OOOOO
OOOOOO
OOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOO
```

Here is my code:

```
int width = 5;

  for (int y = 1; y < width * 2; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < y; x++)
    {
      Console.Write("O");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to do this with two loops, but here is a way to do it with one, and without an `if` condition:

```
for (int y = 1; y < width * 2; y++)
{
    int numOs = width - Math.Abs(width - y);
    for (int x = 0; x < numOs; x++)
    {
        Console.Write("O");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code maybe useful

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication59
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberoflayer = 6, Space, Number;
            Console.WriteLine("Print paramid");
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberoflayer; i++) // Total number of layer for pramid
            {
                for (Space = 1; Space <= (numberoflayer - i); Space++)  // Loop For Space
                    Console.Write(" ");
                for (Number = 1; Number <= i; Number++) //increase the value
                    Console.Write(Number);
                for (Number = (i - 1); Number >= 1; Number--)  //decrease the value
                    Console.Write(Number);
                Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimalist method with only one loop and one ternary expression (`?`) instead of `if`:

```
        int width = 5;
        for (int y = 1; y < width * 2; y++)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(y < width ? y : width * 2 - y, 'O'));
```

Or a version without check:

```
        for (int y = 1; y < width * 2; y++)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(Math.Abs(width * (y / width) - (y % width)), 'O'));
```